# Change PostgreSQL PGDATA variable with systemctl

Tags: 18.04, systemd, services, postgresql

I want to change the postgres' data directory to `/home/postgres/data` editing th postgresql.service instead of change the file `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`.

So, I edited the service with

```
sudo systemctl edit postgresql.service
```

And added this lines:

```
[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=/home/postgres/data
```

And restart de service with `sudo servicetl restart postgresql.service`.

But the data directory don't changed.

Also edit `postgresql@10-main.service` and reboot my laptop, but the data directory didn't change.

How can I change the data directory for postgres using systemctl services or units?

Comment: Does the output of ps aux |grep postgresql show your changed directory after the -D ?  Did you actually move any data there?

Comment: Here: `postgres  9779  0.5  0.1 326888 27056 ?        S    15:25   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
`. Actually if I change the directory in postgres.conf  the server runs correctly, in `/home/postgres/`, and  the directory is owned by user and group. I mean, it seems the PGDATA variable is not used by postgres.

Comment: Well, the old init.d type startup for postgresql explicitly warned you that env variables don't work: # Setting environment variables for the postmaster here does not work; please
# set them in /etc/postgresql/<version>/<cluster>/environment instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data directory must be set in `postgresql.conf` files.

**Why?**

The way that PostgreSQL is packaged on Ubuntu, the `postgresql.service` is an umbrella service that can drive several instances of PostgreSQL running simultaneously (for instance you may have `10/main` and `10/main2` or `9.6/main`) and they cannot share the same $PGDATA, so defining it globally at the level of the umbrella service cannot work.

Also, defining it locally via service units like `postgresql@10-main.service` would cause a problem to commands that manage PG instances like [`pg_lsclusters`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pg_lsclusters.1.html) or [`pg_ctlcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pg_ctlcluster.1.html), as it's not clear how they would find what is the data directory of these instances. Currently these commands parse the configuration files. They do it for the data directory but also for other bits of data such as the port number or the Unix domain socket directories. This part is provided by the [`postgresql-common`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/postgresql-common) package which is pretty much independant from systemd (and predates its adoption).